# Bukkit preventing vine growth

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I'm writing a Bukkit plugin to prevent vine growth, after cancelling BlockGrowEvent, the vine is still growing and spreading. How can I prevent vine growth, and does the event even fire when vine grows?

Code:

```
@EventHandler (ignoreCancelled = true)
public void onVineGrow(BlockGrowEvent event){
    event.setCancelled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BlockGrowEvent` is only called when plants such as wheat, sugar cane, a cactus, a watermelon or a pumpkin grow (and some other plants too). To detect vines spreading, listen to the `BlockSpreadEvent`. Since this event is cancellable, the block to which the vine is spreading will still be air while you're handling the event, so to check if the block is a vine and not a fire block or mushroom spreading, you can look at the new `BlockState` of the block being spread to and check whether its type `event.getNewState().getData().getItemType()` is equal to `Material.VINE`.

Comment: So, `@EventHandler (ignoreCancelled = true)
    public void onVineGrow(BlockSpreadEvent event){
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }`
would cancel all block spreading?

Comment: Yep! As far as I know, it would stop vines, mushrooms and fire from spreading, and maybe some additional blocks that can spread.